# Gulp : delete file after moving to destination folder

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm actually trying to optimize images with Gulp.

Everything works, but I'd like to remove the current image from the source directory after the optimization process.

How can I retrieve this current processed image, to only remove it and not the others (who are not processed yet) ?

I've tried vinyl-paths and the gulp-clean plugin but with no success.

```
gulp.task('delete', function () {
   var vinylPaths = require('vinyl-paths');
   return gulp.src(src, {read: false})
      .pipe(vinylPaths(del));
```

});

Here is a snippet of my gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('default', function() {

var photo  = gulp.src(src);
// One of my filters
var profil_picto_sitter = photo
    .pipe(plumber({
        errorHandler: onError
    }))
    .pipe(imageResize({
        width: 192
    }))
    .pipe(imagemin({
        optimizationLevel: 5,
        progressive: true,
        interlaced: true,
        svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}], use: [pngquant()]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('upload/temp3/'));
```

... other similar filters then :

```
return eventStream.merge(profil_picto_sitter/*, other filters */);
```

Any suggestions ?

Thanks